# Getting HttpListenerContext.User as null while making a Post Request through axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, chromium, httplistener

I am making a post request from Chromium browser that is running on Android 4.4.4 device, the structure of the request is like this

```
var axiosConfig = {
        method: type,
        url: baseURL,
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json",
        timeout: 3000,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(apiUser + ":" + apiPassword),
        },
      };
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        axios(axiosConfig)
          .then(function (response) {
            var result = response;
            resolve(result);
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
          });
      });
```

I have another app running on the same Android device, there is an HttpListener running on it.

```
httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:8001/");
httpListener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
httpListener.IgnoreWriteExceptions = true;
httpListener.Start();
var context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  if (context.User.Identity is HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity)
  {
     return (identity.Name.Equals(UserName) && identity.Password.Equals(Password));
  }
}
```

Now, when I am making a request I am getting null in `context.User`

Can anyone please explain what could be the possible reason for this?